# Convert variable of type *[]foo to *[]bar

Tags: pointers, go, struct, slice

```
type foo struct {
    Field1 int
    Field2 string
}

type bar struct {
    Field1 int
    Field2 string
}

func main() {
    x := foo{1, "Hello"}
    y := bar(x)

    a := [...]foo{x, x}
    b := a[:]

    c := (*[]bar)(&b)

    fmt.Println(x, y, a, b, c)
}
```

I want to convert between two identical structs. Mainly to use different json tags on the two structs. Is there a way to do that? I've tried the example above as well as one with slices of pointers instead of a pointer to a slice. No avail.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/jinzhu/copier

Comment: Also make sure you really understand the reason of using a pointer to a slice. It's almost never you need anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Converting](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) between struct types with identical fields (ignoring tags) is allowed by the language spec.

So create another slice (of type `[]bar`), and use a simple loop to populate it, converting each individual `foo` to `bar`:

```
foos := []foo{
    {1, "Hello"},
    {2, "Bye"},
}

bars := make([]bar, len(foos))
for i, f := range foos {
    bars[i] = bar(f)
}

fmt.Println(foos, bars)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HOstMGOeGRa).

Note that since we're assigning struct values, yes, all the fields are copied. If you don't want to copy the whole structs, you may use pointers:

```
foos := []*foo{
    {1, "Hello"},
    {2, "Bye"},
}

bars := make([]*bar, len(foos))
for i, f := range foos {
    bars[i] = (*bar)(f)
}

fmt.Println(foos, bars)
for i := range foos {
    fmt.Println(foos[i], bars[i])
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3LOPmvfh5sG)):

```
[0x40a0e0 0x40a0f0] [0x40a0e0 0x40a0f0]
&{1 Hello} &{1 Hello}
&{2 Bye} &{2 Bye}
```

As you can see from the output, the pointers in the `foos` and `bars` slices are the same, but the first contains values of type `*foo`, and the latter values of type `*bar`.

Comment: Does this involve copying all of foo? Could I do it with pointers too?